# If $\det(A) = 1$, does that mean $A$ is orthogonal? How to prove?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a matrix $A$ and we know that $\det(A) = 1$. Does it mean that $A$ is orthogonal? How to prove it?

Comment: A matrix with columns $(1,0)^T$ and $(1,1)^T$ has determinant 1 but is not orthogonal.

Comment: Have you tried to disprove it? All it takes is one counterexample......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Take
$J=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right]$, this has $\det J=1$ but is not orthogonal since $J^{-1}\neq J^{\top}$.